# How can I use the jQuery Autocomplete plugin for linked input fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I'm using the [jQuery Autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete). I have two input fields on a form, `inputfield1` and `inputfield2`.

I attached autocomplete to the first field. When the that field loses focus, I want to check if a value was entered and if so, then make an AJAX call to retrieve some "\n"-separated strings and use them to drive autocomplete on the second field.

Below is the code I'm using to do that:

```
/*Receive data from server for autocomplete*/
$("#inputfield1").autocomplete("<url1>"); 

$("#inputfield1").blur(function(){

    // Attach autocomplete if inputfield1 field is not empty
    if($("#inputfield1").val() != ""){
        var url = "<url2>?q="+$("#inputfield1").val();
        $.get(url,function(data){
            result=data.split("\n");
            $("#inputfield2").autocomplete(result);

        });
    }
});
```

But a strange thing is happening: I am able to attach autocomplete to the first field successfully, but I have to give focus twice to the second field in order to use autocomplete on it. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Any progress on this? Was my answer helpful. Can you provide a comment

Comment: Do you know whether the autocomplete plugin will keep re-binding itself over and over on #inputfield2 everytime it blurs?  (Mind you, the plugin may be smart enough to know; I'm just not familiar with this plugin to be smart enough to know...)

Comment: Well? johnswr you provide no feedback at all. What's up?

Answer (score 1):

Try this simplified test. If this works check if your `result` really contains what you think (alert it or write it to console). There could be other characters after splitting (namely whitespace (leading spaces, `\t` or `\r`) try trimming every value of the result array.

```
var data1 = ["a123", "b123", "c123", "d123", "e123", "f123", "g123", "h123", "i123", "j123",   "k123", "l123", "m123", "n123", "o123", "p123", "q123", "r123", "s123", "t123", "u123", "v123", "w123", "x123", "y123", "z123"];
var data2 = 'a123\nb123\nc123\nd123\ne123\nf123\ng123\nh123\ni123\nj123\nk123\nl123\nm123\nn123\no123\np123\nq123\nr123\ns123\nt123\nu123\nv123\nw123\nx123\ny123\nz123';
$("#inputfield1").autocomplete(data1);

$("#inputfield1").blur(function(){
    if($("#inputfield1").val() != ""){
        var result=data2.split("\n");
        $("#inputfield2").autocomplete(result);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using [the latest version](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) of the Autocomplete plugin. [There was a bug in versions prior to 1.1](http://old.nabble.com/autocomplete-bug-when-focus-called-td14174866s27240.html) where if you enabled autocomplete on a field *after* that field had focus (as would happen in your example if you tabbed from the first input field directly into the second) it wouldn't work properly until focus was lost and then restored again...

[Here's a quick demo that shows this construct working with the latest Autocomplete version](http://jsbin.com/ubene3).

Answer (score 1):

I found this code in the current version of the autocomplete plugin:

```
.click(function(event) {
    $(target(event)).addClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
    select();
    // TODO provide option to avoid setting focus again after selection? useful for cleanup-on-focus
    input.focus();
    return false;
```

It seems to put focus back on itself after a click. This might be messing you up.

Instead of handling the blur() event, maybe you'll have better luck if you handle the autocomplete plugin's result() event.

```
/*Receive data from server for autocomplete*/
$("#inputfield1").autocomplete("<url1>"); 

$("#inputfield1").result(function(event, data, formatted){

    // Attach autocomplete if inputfield1 field is not empty
    if(data){
        var url = "<url2>?q="+data;
        $.get(url,function(data1){
                result=data1.split("\n");
                $("#inputfield2").autocomplete(result);

        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you need to select #inputfield2 twice so the autocomplete event binds to it, right?
I'm just thinking.. can it be possible that you are using your tab key on your keyboard to select #inputfield2 and when that doesn't work you select #inputfield2 with your mouse? If so, isn't it possible that the #inputfield1 blur event doesn't kick in until you "unselect" it with your mouse (maybe some kind of bug)?

I haven't tried this, it's just a thought.